# Using ref cursor vs sys_refcursor inside a Stored Procedure Parameters

Tags: plsql

```
CREATE  OR  REPLACE  PROCEDURE GetEmployeesInDept( c OUT  SYS_REFCURSOR)
```

I am having a query related to the above Stored Procedures,
That is while defining the cursor we mentioned it as `sys_refcursor`, and in some, web site I have seen it as REF CURSOR as shown

```
create or replace procedure GetEmployeesInDept( c out ref cursor)
```

Please tell me what is the difference between the ref cursor and `sys_refcursor`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by

```
create or replace procedure GetEmployeesInDept( c out ref cursor)
```

I've not seen this before and I can't get a procedure declared like this to compile.  Could you please provide sample code or links to where you've seen this before?

What you might have seen is something like the following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE demo AS

  TYPE ref_cursor IS REF CURSOR;

  PROCEDURE GetEmployeesInDept(c OUT ref_cursor);

END demo;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY demo AS

  PROCEDURE GetEmployeesInDept(c OUT ref_cursor)
  IS
  BEGIN
    RAISE NO_DATA_FOUND;
  END GetEmployeesInDept;

END demo;
/
```

In this case, we declare a type to be a `REF CURSOR`, and use it as an `OUT` parameter in a stored procedure.

There is no difference between using a type declared as `REF CURSOR` and using `SYS_REFCURSOR`, because `SYS_REFCURSOR` is defined in the `STANDARD` package as a `REF CURSOR` in the same way that we declared the type `ref_cursor`.  In fact, if you're using Oracle 9i or later, look within your Oracle database installation, in `%ORACLE_HOME%\rdbms\admin\stdspec.sql`, and you should find the following line somewhere in there:

```
type sys_refcursor is ref cursor;
```

`SYS_REFCURSOR` was introduced in Oracle 9i.  You may find various types declared as `REF CURSOR` in PL/SQL code that was written before Oracle 9i was released.

Comment: See also [Cursor variables](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e17126/static.htm#i7106) in _Oracle Database PL/SQL Language Reference_ (11.2).

Answer (score 4):

There are two forms of ref Cursor the strong REF CURSOR
and the weak REF CURSOR. PL/SQL is a statically typed language, and the weak REF
CURSOR is one of the few dynamically typed constructs supported.

(statically typed language: that was mean that type checking
is performed at compile time not at runtime)

**When you defined a SYS_REFCURSOR is a predefined weak REF CURSOR type.**

A strong ref cursor it's something like this:

TYPE book_data_t IS REF CURSOR RETURN book%ROWTYPE;

cause associate the cursor variable with a specific record structure.

Answer (score 2):

There can be one difference between the two, I can think off is `ref_cursor` can be `STRONG` or `WEAK` type whereas `SYS_REFCURSOR` is always weak type as it is defined that way.

Answer (score -2):

Check the following Difference :

1)Using ref cursor

```
                        SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE package p19
                          2  as
                          3         PROCEDURE p;
                          4  END;
                          5  /
```

Package CREATEd.

```
                      1  CREATE OR REPLACE package BODY p19
                      2  as
                      3     type s is ref cursor;
                      4     PROCEDURE p
                      5     as
                      6     BEGIN
                      7     NULL;
                      8     END;
                      9* END;
                      SQL> /

                     Package BODY CREATEd.
```

2)Using Sys_Refcursor:

```
        SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE package p19
             2  as
             3      PROCEDURE p;
             4  END;
             5  /
```

Package CREATED.

SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

```
                1  CREATE OR REPLACE package BODY p19
                2  as
                3   s sys_refcursor;
                4   PROCEDURE p
                5   as
                6   BEGIN
                7   NULL;
                8   END;
                9* END;
               SQL> /
```

Warning: Package BODY CREATEd with compilation errors.

SQL> show err
Errors for PACKAGE BODY P19:

### LINE/COL ERROR

3/4      PL/SQL: Item ignored
3/4      PLS-00994: Cursor Variables cannot be declared as part of a
         package

Comment: Sorry, but your examples are misleading. In your first example, you're simply declaring a package-level type. In your second example, you're declaring a package-level variable. These are two different things.

Comment: Basically my Intension is to let you know the main Difference between sys_refcursor and refcursor .

Comment: Basically, you have not shown any difference, because you are comparing apples (types) with oranges (variables).

Comment: i mean we can't declare sys_refcursor outside as a global variable but whereas we can declare REFCURSOR at global level.for information check the following link https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::NO::P11_QUESTION_ID:14188501024541

Comment: You can declare refcursor **type** at global level. Try declaring a **variable** of type `s` in your example-1-package.

Comment: yeah we can declare REFCURSOR at global level but we can't declare sys_refcursor

Comment: No, you can't declare `refcursor` **variable** at global level. You only can declare `refcursor` **type** at global level.